# Wordpress Event posts

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins

I Need to make a event list in wordpress, show up by: "today" - "week" - "month" and all this show just my post. Witch is the best way to do that? 
The author must just add the date and time of event and its appear in the current category us well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the possibility for the author to add the date of an event, use the add_meta_boxes_{$post_slug} action.

This action allows to configure and print a new metabox in any post (choosen) post screen.

```
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes');
 add_action('save_post', 'save_sticked_metabox');

 function adding_custom_meta_boxes(){
     add_meta_box(
        'sticked-list',
        __( 'Featured list', $this->plugin_text_domain ),
        'sticked_list_Render',
        'post',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
 }
 function sticked_list_Render(){
     global $post;

    $sticked = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sticked', true);

    $checked = '';
    if($sticked != '' && isset($sticked)){
        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sticked" value="true" <?php echo $checked;?> > <?php _e('Check to set as pre-defined list', $this->plugin_text_domain);?>

    <?
 }

 function save_sticked_metabox($post_id, $post){
     if(isset($_POST['sticked'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sticked', 'true');
    }
    else{
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'sticked');
    }
 }
```

This is just an example to show how to print a new metabox in the edit-post admin screen. You'll need to change the "sticked_list_render" to print a date & time picker.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to add event date. And after that its must appear in write field in front end "today" week month. 3 tabs or something